# what to consider when using react with type script?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-router, typescript2.0

I know react but I never used it with Typescript which I know the basics so it would be very generous if you can provide a tutorial , article or advice that helps me on the project

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html

Answer (score 1):

You can of course check the typescript [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html) to learn more about the basics of typescript.
The docs have also a specific section on React and Webpack [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html).
You can also check out this [tutorial](https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react/).